# PHP remote image opening in browser but imagecreatefromgif : failed to open stream: operation failed

Tags: php

I run a shopping site and am trying to save a copy of this remote gif image to my server as jpg.

```
$i='http://www.medexsupply.com/images/RO1R910C.GIF';

$imagejpg = imagecreatefromgif($i);
```

and it gives following errors :

```
Warning: imagecreatefromgif(): Couldn't resolve host name in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx/file.php on line 46

Warning: imagecreatefromgif(http://www.medexsupply.com/images/RO1R910C.GIF): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx/file.php on line 46
```

on line 46, the code is 
`$imagejpg = imagecreatefromgif($i);`

I have dedicated server with 128MB memory limit for php scripts.

allow_url_fopen is on.

I can modify any setting on my server.

I could copy thousands of other remote images but not this image and images from some other sites.

Can someone help.

Please reply if you would like to know more information.

Thank you

Comment: Try using the resolved IP address in place of the hostname. `2.20.242.177` = www.medexsupply.com

Comment: If you put the URL into the browser, do you get the valid image?  Some sites do not allow hot-linking of images and return errors if you try to do so.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to tell the world that *allow_url_fopen* is on

Answer (score 1):

There is a DNS issue with your domain, which explains the "could not resolve host" message.

From my browser, I can access your images.  Yet from a different machine, I get:

```
$ dig www.medexsupply.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> www.medexsupply.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

At this point in time, it could be possible that Sandy is the cause, as I see you are hosted with Rackspace in New York and, from the machine that gave the error above, I cannot ping their nameservers.

Comment: I concur, I've tested the OP's original 2 lines of code and I read the image fine, so this seems pretty likely.

Answer (score 0):

A URL can be used as a filename with this function "imagecreatefromgif " if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.thaicreate.com/php-manual/filesystem.configuration.html#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename and List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for a [list of supported URL protocols](http://www.thaicreate.com/php-manual/wrappers.html).